# if $x\le a,x\le f(x)\le a$ and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ then $\lim x_n=a$?

Tags: real-analysis

consider a function $f:R\to R$ is it true that for all $x\le a,x\le f(x)\le a$ and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ then $\lim x_n=a$.

Attempts: I shown that $\{x_n\}$ is a  convergent sequence but i am not sure how to show that or disprove that $\lim x_n=a$

Comment: i am not really sure if I got your question right, it sound a bit like a fix point theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit isn't necessary $a$, for example taking $x_0=0$, $a=1$ and 
$$f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]\\x\mapsto 0.$$

As Did mentioned I could have missunterstood the question. Never the less 
$$ f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
x\mapsto x
$$ will work fine.

Comment: How is $x\leqslant f(x)$? Johnny: are you actually READING the answers you accept?

Comment: @Did mh? f(0)=0. Maybe I missunterstood the question

Comment: Anyway the onus is on the OP, not on you.

Comment: The question is not very well written, taking any $a\not\in R$ would be a counterexample. But the $f(x)=x$ thing should work for every thing that i can think of right now

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest to draw the graph of the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x+\sin^2x$. In words, the function $f$ is increasing, its graph is above the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ and it meets $\Delta$ at every point $(k\pi,k\pi)$ with $k$ integer.

Then $x_n\to k\pi$ if one starts from $(k-1)\pi\lt x_0\leqslant k\pi$ for some integer $k$. Thus the case $x_0=\frac\pi2$ and $a=2\pi$ disproves the conjecture in the post since $x_n\to\pi$ when $n\to\infty$.